# data frame in r with plot bar and data

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I would really appreciate your help with this question

The dataframe below, 'df', generates a bar plot.

item    number  year
a   400 2014
b   150 2015
c   300 2011
a   300 2015
c   400 2011
c   100 2011
b   250 2014

Complete the following code to generates the bar plot below

newdf <- df %>%

(number = number/100) %>%
group_by(

) %>%

(m = median(
))

[This is the bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxsrF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>%
  mutate(number = number/100) %>%
  group_by(item)%>%
  summarise(m = median(number)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=item,y=m))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(item = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "c", "b"), number = c(400L, 
150L, 300L, 300L, 400L, 100L, 250L), year = c(2014L, 2015L, 2011L, 
2015L, 2011L, 2011L, 2014L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```